# Firebase dataRef.transaction() returns wrong snapshot

Tags: firebase

I'd like to assign an incremental number to users while they click on #div1 or #div2. Multiple user from different devices can get their subsequent number without problem with the following codes:

```
$("#div1").click(function(event) {
    doBtn();
}

$("#div2").click(function(event) {
    doBtn();
}

function doBtn() {
    counterRef.transaction( function(currentData) {
      if (currentData === null) {
        return 1; 
      } else {
        // increase the counterRef by 1
        return currentData + 1;
      }
    }, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
      if (error) {
      } else if (!committed) {
      } else {
        // upon counterRef updated successfully, add a child {user: "userId", counter: xxxx} to ListRef
        // (xxxx is the increased counter number)
        ListRef.push({
            user: "userId",
            counter: snapshot.val()
        });
      }
    } );
}

counterRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log( "Current number is " + snapshot.val() );
}

ListRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log( "Your number is " + snapshot.val().counter );
}
```

However, if the user click the same button (or clicking `#div1` and `#div2` alternatively) rapidly, they will get the following results:

> Current number is 1
>   Current number is 2
>   Current number is 3
>   Current number is 4
>   Current number is 5
>   Current number is 6
>   Current number is 7
>   Current number is 8
>
> Your number is 1
>   Your number is 3
>   Your number is 3
>   Your number is 4
>   Your number is 5
>   Your number is 6
>   Your number is 8
>   Your number is 8

It seems that the snapshot value in `function(error, committed, snapshot)` cannot get the concurrent value from `counterRef` while being increased.

Am I using the `.transaction()` wrong?

Please help.

Comment: Had a look at this today [and reproduced the behavior you've described](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/UHDt7/4/). Not sure if there's anything wrong there. Pinging the dev team for some insight.

Comment: This error only happens for rapid-trigger from the same machine. I've tried the same thing but with different devices, it seems will return results as expected (no counter number duplication).

My temporally solution is to disable the button before .transaction() and re-enable it after .push(). Too shame that I cannot do multiple actions while offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, based on @Kato's reproduction, I think this is expected behavior based on our current implementation.

Basically, if you do multiple transactions rapidly (or while you're offline), we'll end up batching them together and performing them as a single batch, and the final snapshot each one gets will be the final snapshot after all of them ran.

I understand this may not always be ideal.  We'll look into whether we could perhaps change this behavior in the future.