# Notification of final commit in batch transactions

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an Angular app that allows users to "checkout" selected objects (and they would control those objects until put back in the pool of objects), which can number between 1 and many.  Using a for loop on ref.transaction(), I get a commit for each object committed. Based on the answer in this question [Firebase dataRef.transaction() returns wrong snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343531/firebase-dataref-transaction-returns-wrong-snapshot/23420860#23420860), on the server end these may be batched and there may be no way to get an accurate count reference from the batched transactions.  How can I tell if the commits to all submitted have been accomplished (that is, the processing of the batch has been completed) and the final count of the commits?  For example, I could loop through 50 requests for "checkouts" and may only get back less than 50 commits because another user checked out an object before the transaction was completed. I'm not having success using the transaction callback to do this.

```
for(var y=0;y<$scope.stuffSelected.length;y++) {
    var myObjectsRef = new Firebase(thisFBRef);
    myObjectsRef.transaction(
        function(anobject) {
            var update = {checkedout:true, checkout_by:'Sammy B', checkout_date: new Date().toUTCString()}; 
            for(var prop in update){ 
                anobject[prop] = update[prop]; 
            } 
            return anobject; 
        }, function(error, committed, snapshot) { 
            if(committed && !error){ 
                console.log('Commit successful ...'); // need someway to identify when this loop is finished 
            } 
        }
    );
```

Comment: Without a minimal example of the code that shows your problem, this question will be closed.

Comment: for(var y=0;y<$scope.stuffSelected.length;y++){
  var myObjectsRef = new Firebase(thisFBRef);
myObjectsRef.transaction(function(anobject) {
  var update = {checkedout:true,  checkout_by:'Sammy B', checkout_date: new Date().toUTCString()};
  for(var prop in update){
    anobject[prop] = update[prop];
  }
  return anobject;
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
       if(committed && !error){
           console.log('Commit successful ...');
           // need someway to identify when this loop is finished 
        }
});

Comment: SO the idea is that after the last commit is received, the process can be passed on to a function like a DOM status indicator

Comment: Since you clearly used the suggestion from my answer to your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24704698/209103), it would be nice if you would accept that answer (by clicking the large check mark to the left of it). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Sorry - but your response was a comment and not an answer, and I appreciate the comment. Looks like the check mark only appears for answers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact that you're trying to roll multiple parallel asynchronous calls into a loop.

### Fire the transactions sequentially

You can solve the problem by firing the transactions sequentially. So you'll only start a transaction for the next item after the completion callback for the current transaction.

```
function checkout() {
    if (stuffToCheckout.length > 0) {
        myObjectsRef.child(stuffToCheckout[0]).transaction(function(anobject) {
            var update = {checkedout:true, checkout_by:'Sammy B', checkout_date: new Date().toUTCString()}; 
            for(var prop in update){ 
                anobject[prop] = update[prop]; 
            } 
            return anobject; 
        }, function(error, committed, snapshot) { 
            if(committed && !error){ 
                console.log('Commit successful ...');
                stuffToCheckout.shift();
                checkout();
            }
        }
    }
}
checkout([/* populate this list with the ids of items to check out*/]);
```

### Listen for the updated value

Alternatively you can look at deriving whether anything is still checked out from the data structure. You can do this by listening for 'child_changed' on the items and simply tracking the checked_out flag:

```
var checkedOut = {};
items.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    var val = snapshot.val();
    if (val.checked_out) {
        checkedOut[snapshot.name()] = true;
    }
    else {
        delete checkedOut[snapshot.name()];
        if (checkedOut.length == 0) {
            alert('Nothing is checked out anymore');
        }
    }
});
```

If this leads to too much state in your client, you could consider keeping the checked-out items in a different ref. When the user checks out an item, you simply move it to this `CheckedOut` ref. That way you only have to monitor if that ref has any children.

### Update

I just realized that listening for the updated value won't work, since the `child_changed` event will fire locally (so you'll see the local change, before it is committed on the server). Handling the transactions sequentially still seems like a viable option.

### Update 2

I may have been wrong in that last update. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/J8jsb/) the `child_changed` event doesn't fire for `transaction`s that have been aborted (by returning `undefined`).

The most relevant bit of the code is:

```
items.child(i).transaction(function(current_value) {
    if (!current_value.checked_out_by) {
        // not checked out -> check it out
        current_value.checked_out_by = username;
    }
    else if (current_value.checked_out_by == username) {
        // checked out by me -> check it in
        delete current_value.checked_out_by;
    }
    else {
        // checked out by someone else -> abort transaction
        return;
    }
    return current_value;
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error callback: '+error);
        throw error;
    } else if (!committed) {
        console.log('not committed callback');
        console.log(snapshot.val()); // this is unmodified, so no need to update
    } else {
        console.log('success callback: '+snapshot.val().name);
    }
});
```

Where I call `console.log(snapshot.val())` it shows me the unmodified value, which is the same value I got in the last `child_changed` event before that. I tested with a few browser windows on a single machine (IE, Firefox, Chrome) and as far I as can see the state remains consistent between my clients.